# Python object @property

Tags: python, new-style-class

I'm trying to create a point class which defines a property called "coordinate".  However, it's not behaving like I'd expect and I can't figure out why.

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, coord=None):
        self.x = coord[0]
        self.y = coord[1]

    @property
    def coordinate(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

    @coordinate.setter
    def coordinate(self, value):
        self.x = value[0]
        self.y = value[1]

p = Point((0,0))
p.coordinate = (1,2)

>>> p.x
0
>>> p.y
0
>>> p.coordinate
(1, 2)
```

It seems that p.x and p.y are not getting set for some reason, even though the setter "should" set those values.  Anybody know why this is?

Comment: What happens if you try to print `p.coordinate` just after you have instantiated the object, before trying to change it?

Comment: This is a gotcha old-style-classes-vs-new-style-classes and you might expect either `property()` or the IDE would catch it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property getter/setter have no effect in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163940/property-getter-setter-have-no-effect-in-python-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `property` method (and by extension, the `@property` decorator) [requires a new-style class](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) i.e. a class that subclasses `object`.

For instance,

```
class Point:
```

should be

```
class Point(object):
```

Also, the `setter` attribute (along with the others) was added in Python 2.6.

Comment: But if I create a `property` inside a classic class, error raised?

Answer (score 4):

It will work if you derive Point from object:

```
class Point(object):
    # ...
```