# python property and new class style

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-2.x

I tried to use property decorator and its setter like the flowing

```
class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius=0):
        self.__radius = radius 

    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self.__radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if (radius > 0):
            self.__radius = radius
        else:
            raise ValueError

c = Circle()
c.radius = -1
```

But nothing is happening in python 2.x.
Only python 3.x can raise the ValueError.

However, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163940/python-property-getter-setter-confusion)
The post advises to use new class style (inherit object),
but I don't know what features in new class style let it work.
I want to know the relationship between property and object.

Comment: I receive a ValueError in 2.7.6.

Comment: The code above raises ValueError in python 2.7.

Because you are using new style classes already (by inheriting object).

Why do you want to avoid new style objects?

Comment: Is this the actual code you tried? This class inherits from `object`; did you remember to inherit from `object` when you actually tried it? Copy/paste your code from the actual source file, if at all possible.

Comment: i don't want to avoid use new style. i just want to know why new style can work.

Comment: sorry, the code in my origin post already used new class style. i update it and it wouldn't work in 2.x now.

Answer (score 3):

Properties are descriptors.  [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) describes where the descriptor functionality "comes from":

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`.

Properties won't work with old-style classes, because old-style classes don't inherit from `object`, and, as that quote says, the machinery for making descriptors work is provided by `object`.

There is no straightforward way to add this functionality to an old-style class, because `__getattribute__` also doesn't work on old-style classes.  You would have to store some separate dictionary of properties and then use `__getattr__` to map attribute access to them.  However, there's no reason to do this, because there is no reason to not use new-style classes every single time.

Comment: so, in other words, if i implement descriptor of radius and it will work?

Comment: @FreedomKnight: The point is that you can't do it just on `radius`.  The class itself has to provide the infrastructure.  I added a bit to my answer, but I don't understand what your goal is.  Just always use new-style classes and forget old-style classes even exist.

Comment: my goal just want to know the mechanism in python. i don't  want to know how to use but know things behind these. finally, thanks for your answer