# Python @property setter not setting from instance call

Tags: python, getter-setter, python-object

I have a class (simplified view):

```
class Record():

    OrderStatusMapping = dict(zip(['0', '1', '2'], ['NEWO', 'PARF', 'FILL']))

    def __init__(self):
        self._OrderStatus = None

    @property
    def OrderStatus(self):
        return self.OrderStatusMapping.get(self._OrderStatus)

    @OrderStatus.setter
    def OrderStatus(self, value):
        self._OrderStatus = value
```

Now this class is called from a different module and used as below:

```
from core.record import Record
r = Record()
r.OrderStatus = '2'
```

For some reason however when I later call `r.OrderStatus` call it returns `'2'` not `'FILL'`.
Debugging the variables in VisualStudio I can see that actually it appears when I call `r.OrderStatus = '2'` it never uses the `@OrderStatus.setter` but instead seems to make it's own variable `OrderStatus` on the fly, not using the setter and hence never setting `self._OrderStatus`.

Am I doing something obviously bad in using getters and setters? Why are they not being called as they should be?

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Which version of Python are you on?  if on Python 2 then you should inherit your class from `object`, `property` only works from new-style classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python object @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337935/python-object-property)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property getter/setter have no effect in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163940/property-getter-setter-have-no-effect-in-python-2)

Comment: As a side note, you should use `enum` for states to enforce validity of the value at any time ([there's a backport for 2.x](https://pypi.org/project/enum34/)). Or at the very least, check input in the setter.

Comment: @Jakob: could you at least confirm the version of python you are using?  The default `python` tag assumes python 3, if you are still on Python 2 then please use the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descriptors and hence properties are only supported in new style classes. You need to inherit from the Object class always to make it new style, and using this the property setter works as expected.

```
In [29]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:class Record(object):
:
:    OrderStatusMapping = dict(zip(['0', '1', '2'], ['NEWO', 'PARF', 'FILL']))
:
:    def __init__(self):
:        self._OrderStatus = None
:
:    @property
:    def OrderStatus(self):
:        return self.OrderStatusMapping.get(self._OrderStatus)
:
:    @OrderStatus.setter
:    def OrderStatus(self, value):
:        self._OrderStatus = value
:<EOF>

In [30]: r = Record()

In [33]: r.OrderStatus = '2'

In [34]: r.OrderStatus
Out[34]: 'FILL'
```

Comment: There are at least two duplicates of this question, probably more.  With such an obvious mistake it is always worth checking before you answer.

Comment: Got it, i will delete mine too then :)